# Auto Fill Lookup Column

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, lookup-column, connected-web-parts

I believe I am starting off on the right foot by using a lookup column.  I am seeking a way for when a user enters in a order number the number auto populates in a choice column.  So basically every time someone enters in a order number the number appears in the form choice column. Therefore, users after them could potential choose the same order number to add documents to it...etc.

This may not be clear.  Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like an autofill in your field . Check this out http://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/